How to identify hot spots in one-dimension
I am looking to identify stretches of a road along which a notably high number of accidents occur. My data can be represented as a two column table in which each row represents one accident, and the two columns give the distance of the accident from the start of the road and the number of vehicles passing that point per year, respectively.
There are plenty of procedures (using Moran's I or the Getis-Ord statistic, for instance) for identifying hot spots of density in two dimensions. Is there a statistic for identifying significant hot spots in a one-dimensional setting like mine?

What constitutes a "hot spot"?  Would it be locations with large numbers of accidents, or with large numbers of accidents relative to number of vehicles passing by, or large numbers of accidents relative to some model that estimates how many accidents might occur at every location, or possibly something else?  Whatever it might be, along any road that is a manifold--that is, without intersections or splits--you can always apply any 2D method you like merely by thickening the road very slightly.

@whuber To simplify things, I probably should have just described the case where traffic volume is constant along the entire road. In that case, I guess I'm thinking about accidents as a likely inhomogenous Poisson process. I am then wanting to identify  sections of the road that have such a high density of accidents relative to other sections that it'd be highly unlikely to see so many there if the underlying intensity of the process was homogeneous. So maybe I'm looking for a one-dimensional scan statistic of some sort?

@whuber I like your suggestion of straightening the road into a line, buffering it a tiny bit, and then applying a 2D method. I had considered that, but wasn't (and still am not) sure whether the 2D setting for which the statistics were designed would render their inference invalid what really is a 1D setting.

@whuber To elaborate, I worry that I end up with all of the off-road areas effectively working as a bunch of false non-occurences in the smoothing/density estimation portion of the algorithm. Alternatively put, if the statistic suffers from edge effects, my entire area of analysis becomes one big edge.

Thank you for the clear explanations; the points you raise are all legitimate. There are some 2D methods that don't have edge effects or that can be implemented without them (usually based on simulations).  You can also apply all kinds of clustering methods: there's a wealth of options. Search our site for 1D clustering to learn about those approaches. I can't recall any thread specifically asking how to test $H_0:$ a process is homogeneous Poisson vs $H_A:$ the process is inhomogeneous Poisson (in any dimension), but Ripley's K is useful.

@whuber Super. Thanks for the suggestions. If I don't come across something simpler, I'll use the R package spatstat to run some simulations. First, though, I'll search here for "1D clustering" and will also delve into this suggestion from Adrian Baddeley (one author of spatstat) in his response to a similar question from a few years ago.
